# Regex for camel case with blacklist

Tags: regex, vb.net

Together with my team we use below regex pattern to describe upper camel case that fits to our needs. Quite simple one - many similar we can found in the internet.

```
^[A-Z]+(?:[A-Z]*[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$
```

We would like to improve it by adding blacklist to this expression. We can divide this blacklist entries into two categories:

1. Words that cannot be in the beginning of the string (for example "Bool" because instead of this we must use "Flag")
2. Words that cannot be at the end or in the middle of the string (for example "Flag", "Path", "Url", "Counter" because those are prefixes and they must be at the beginning)

For sure we have to use blacklist approach instead of whitelist because there are much less words that can be forbidden than allowed and not all strings must start with prefix)

I would really grateful if someone can help me to implement this blacklist into our existing regex pattern.

Regards,
Tomek

@Edit:
I think that I did not correctly explain my blacklist idea. What I meant is that those expressions mentioned in the blacklist should NOT be matched - they should be automatically excluded.

@Edit1:
To be matched cases (correct)

```
FlagDataExist
PathInputFile
UrlLoggingPage
OtherCamelCase
VarValue
IntValue
CounterValue
```

NOT to be matched cases (incorrect):

- `BoolDataExist` (blacklist #1 is true)
- `InputFilePath` (blacklist #2 is true)
- `LoggingUrlPage` (blacklist #2 is true)
- `otherCamelCase` (because it is lower camel case)
- `varValue` (because it is lower camel case)
- `intValue` (because it is lower camel case)
- `counterValue` (because it is lower camel case)

Comment: Does it have to be RegEx? I'm not saying that it can't be accomplished (because it can), but it would be a massive mess that would be difficult to maintain. The simplest solution is to create a collection for each category and add your blacklisted words to the collection, then iterate over the collection to see if the word meets the requirement of the category.

Comment: Yes we need RegEx for this. Tool that we need to validate those strings enforced us to use Regular Expressions

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to match with your current pattern and then remove any matches that conflict with the other specifications. https://regex101.com/r/nUN6rW/1

Comment: _Tool that we need to validate those strings enforced us to use Regular Expressions_ - grhh ;)

Comment: In your point 1 you say that insted of `Bool` you must use `Flag` and **at the same time** in point 2 you say that *Words that cannot be in the string (for example, **Flag**...)* What?

Comment: Those two list does not exclude itself:) "Flag" must be used as prefix only (no suffix or in the middle of the string). I edited it a bit make it more clear. By list 1 I want to avoid using incorrect suffix and by list 2 I want to make sure that someone use prefixes at the beginning of the string - NOT in the middle or at the end

Comment: Please, provide us some examples covering all cases.

Comment: Yeah sure, examples added. Hope they give better view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. You can add other values to prefixes and blacklist. You use `Join` to create alternate pattern (for instance, you can use paramater which accepts array with these values, and then you `Join` them).

```
Sub Main(args As String())
    Dim strings =
    {
        "FlagDataExist",  'True
        "PathInputFile",  'True
        "UrlLoggingPage", 'True
        "OtherCamelCase", 'True
        "VarValue",       'True
        "IntValue",       'True
        "CounterValue",   'True
        "BoolDataExist",  'False
        "InputFilePath",  'False
        "LoggingUrlPage", 'False
        "otherCamelCase", 'False
        "varValue",       'False
        "intValue",       'False
        "counterValue"    'False
    }

    Dim prefixes = String.Join("|", {"Flag", "Path", "Url", "Counter"})
    Dim blackList = String.Join("|", {"Bool"})
    For Each s In strings
        Dim m = Regex.Match(s, $"^(?!({blackList}))(?![A-Za-z]+({prefixes}))(?=[A-Z])")
        Console.WriteLine($"'{s}' -> {m.Success}")
    Next
End Sub

' Output:
'   'FlagDataExist'  -> True
'   'PathInputFile'  -> True
'   'UrlLoggingPage' -> True
'   'OtherCamelCase' -> True
'   'VarValue'       -> True
'   'IntValue'       -> True
'   'CounterValue'   -> True
'   'BoolDataExist'  -> False
'   'InputFilePath'  -> False
'   'LoggingUrlPage' -> False
'   'otherCamelCase' -> False
'   'varValue'       -> False
'   'intValue'       -> False
'   'counterValue'   -> False
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'll answer more in depth based on the comment I left. A one size fits all pattern for this problem would just be messy (and honestly more work than it's worth). You're better off using your current pattern to get a bunch of matches and then run them through some other patterns, removing anything that matches them. [This pattern](https://regex101.com/r/nUN6rW/2) will function as your general blacklist, matching any entry with one of the blacklisted words in it. To add to the blacklist, simply add a `|` followed by the word you want to blacklist.

To blacklist entries that start with a specific word, [the pattern is very similar.](https://regex101.com/r/nUN6rW/3)

And finally, to blacklist entries that end with a specific word, [this should do the trick](https://regex101.com/r/nUN6rW/4)